# Env variables for plugins in PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, plugins, environment-variables

I am running PHP on Windows. PHP plugins on Windows are just DLL's in an extensions folder, and I can do little to configure these plugins.

For example, the ADAP plugin (which is OpenLDAP itself) has settings that I can't change on runtime. Luckily, OpenLDAP allows me to change some of these settings by messing with the environment variables. I tried setting them up on runtime by adding both:

```
// this apparently works on Linux
putenv('VARIABLE=value');
// tried this one as well
$_ENV['VARIABLE'] = 'value';
```

But that didn't work. I had to add that to Windows' environment variables (and that did work), but that's too much of a pain in the rear and will break the code when I move it. Is there a better way to do this or I'll have just to deal with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the environment variables before the dll extension is loaded. That is, don't load the dll via php.ini, but use putenv() and afterwards dl(). Usually a DLL should share the environment variables with the main process, but you never know.

Alternatively set any required options from within .htaccess using **SetEnv**. This is at least portable for Apache webservers. Come to think of it, you should also try **apache_setenv()** if you are running mod_php and not the FastCGI version.

Btw, there have always been PHP bugs for putenv, http://bugs.php.net/50690, might be the case here.